# How do I handle $dx$ in $u$-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I am having trouble with an example of $u$-substitution:

$$ \int \frac{x}{x²+1}dx$$

In the next step they write:

Let $u = x^2+1$ which seems like a good choice. Then $du = 2x$ and that is also obvious, but then: $xdx = \frac{1}{2}$ and then use that to do something as I don't understand.

How is the $xdx$ value calculated and what are they using it for? As you see, I am having trouble with understanding $u$-substitution in general....

Comment: You said $du=2x$ but actually it should be $du=2xdx$ and $xdx=\frac{1}{2}$ also doesn't make sense.

Comment: I quote @i.ozturk, from $\mathrm du = 2x\mathrm dx$ you get $x\mathrm dx = \frac{\mathrm du}{2}$. I proposed an edit with the corrections.

Comment: @rubik Edits are not intended for this type of change.

Comment: It should be $du = 2xdx, xdx = \frac{1}{2}du$ sorry!

Comment: @AlexR: Oh ok. I was suspecting that I couldn't change the post like that, but I tried anyway. Thank you for clarifying it to me.

Comment: here is another flavor of u-substitution that you may want to try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813436/getting-rid-of-square-root-in-this-integration/903050#903050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose $u=x^2+1$, then taking the derivative with respect to $x$ gives:
$$\frac{\textrm{d}u}{\textrm{d}x}=2x.$$
Therefore $\textrm{d}u=2x\textrm{d}x$ or $x\textrm{d}x=\textrm{d}u/2$. Now your integral is written:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}\textrm{d}u,$$
which is easier to solve than the original integral. It is equal to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln{|u|}\ =\, \frac{1}{2}\ln{(x^2+1)}.$$

Comment: For the sake of correctness, $\int \frac1u \mathrm du = [\ln |u|]$. (Note the absolute value). The final result is correct, though.

Comment: @AlexR: You're right. Thank you.

Comment: I get it now, thanks! if I write it like $int\frac{xdx}{x²+1}$ I found it easier to understand...

Answer (score 0):

With $u=x^2+1$ and thus $du=2x dx$ you get
$$\int\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}du=\frac{1}{2}\ln|u| = \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)$$

Comment: For the sake of correctness, $\int \frac1u \mathrm du = [\ln |u|]$. (Note the absolute value). The final result is correct, though.